# Laravel "escapeshellarg() has been disabled for security reasons" workaround

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

In my Lavarvel (5.4.7) application on a shared host I get the error "escapeshellarg() has been disabled for security reasons" when trying to run a cron job through Artisan like `Artisan::call('doSomething');`

Enabling escapeshellarg is not an option, so I'm looking for the most decent work around without having to change any of the classes in the vendor folder.
Some possible solutions I could come up with but haven't figured out how to do are:

1) Replace the native escapeshellarg with a custom one.

2) Override the Symfony\Component\Process\ProcessUtils class

3) Override the ProcessUtils::escapeArgument function (which calls the escapeshellarg) so that other classes in the vendor folder start using the overwritten class/function (but without having to change or override those classes themselves).

Is there a way to do this? or is there another way to workaround the error?

Comment: 4) Get a decent hosting provider

Answer (score 0):

Just create your own escapeshellarg function and replace

`escapeshellarg($input) function` to

```
$this->my_escapeshellarg($input)


function my_escapeshellarg($input)
    {
      $input = str_replace('\'', '\\\'', $input);

      return '\''.$input.'\'';
    }
```

Comment: where can i add this function??